# Apache2 Disable Directory Index for Root Directory

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 and Apache2. I'll be hosting multiple sites, I've figured out how to disable each site's directory in the VirtualHosts, but when I put the sever  IP address in, I get a directory index for all the sites that are being hosted.

I tried adding "Options All -Indexes" to httpd.conf, but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `default` from the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. After that Apache will serve the side which is available first. You can control that by naming your per vhost file in either alphabetical order or by starting the filename with numbers.

Check `apachectl -S`shows the order.

For my setups I use something like this:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-domain.tld
                             001-domain2.tld
                             002-next-domain.tld
```

And in that way I control which vhost is served in which order. IP falls back to the first found.

Comment: Opened up default and added "-" before Indexes. That did the trick. Thanks!